# lock redis key when two processes are accessing the same key

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Application 1 set a value in Redis.
And we  have two instance of application 2 which are running and we would like only one instance should read this value from Redis (please note application 2 takes around 30 sec to 1 min  process data )

Can Instance-1 application 2  acquire lock redis key which is created by application 1  , so that instance-2 of application 2 will not read and do the same operation ?

Comment: You should try Redis List or Redis Stream.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no concept of record lock in Redis. If you need to achieve some sort of locking you have to use another set of data structures to mimic that behavior. For example

- **List:** You can use a list and then `POP` the item from the list or...
- **Redis Stream:** Using Redis Stream with ConsumerGroup so that each consumer in your Group only sees a portion of the whole data the needs to be processed and it guarantees you that, when an item is delivered to a consumer, it is not going to be delivered to another one.